# Moving a layer in Gimp

Tags: gimp

I am trying to move a layer in Gimp. However, it does not allow me to do so. Instead, I get this mouse pointer:

[image]

What does that mean? Why doesn't it allow me to move the layer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you have selected the Move Selection option in the Tool Options, but you have no selection to move.

[image]

Choose the Move Layer option instead

[image]